# Как заменить символы?

Tags: javascript

Как заменить символ в ссылках?
Пробую вот так, но он просто убирает символ, при символе # все ок

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => { 
   a.href = a.href.replace(/@/, "123")
})
```

```css
a {
  pointer-events: none;
}

a::before {
  content: attr(href);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://@test"></a>
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142499/discussion-on-question-by-jcjdjh---); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Этот вопрос оставьте, а все удалите))

Comment: Заменил @ на # и все отработало как надо. Однако если посмотреть, то браузер убирает лидирующий @ если перед ним нет других символов, поэтому замена @ на 123 не срабатывает, т.к. нет @

Comment: Не надо дублировать вопросы. Достаточно отредактировать иходный

Answer (score 0):

Тег `<a>` это тег для якорей. Аттрибут `href` у него должна быть ссылкой. Если вы задаете кривую ссылку в аттрибут `href`, она по возможности будет исправлена.

```js
document.querySelector(`button#fix`).addEventListener(`click`, (event) => {
  document.querySelectorAll(`a`).forEach((a) => {
    a.href = a.href;
  })
});
```

```css
a {
  pointer-events: none;
}

a::before {
  content: attr(href);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://@test"></a><br/>
<button id="fix">Fix</button>
```

И тут `replace(/@/, "123")` не при чем.